# inhibit_all_warnings! not working in CocoaPods

Tags: compiler-warnings, cocoapods

I'd like to turn off warnings for CocoaPods in my project, but the setting `inhibit_all_warnings!` doesn't work.

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod "AFNetworking", "2.3.1"
...
```

Warnings are shown nevertheless, and I see that "Inhibiti All Warnings" in my Pods-project is still set to `no`. What am I missing?

I'm using Cocoapods version 0.33.1, and I get compiler warnings from the SVGKit project, e.g.

```
/Users/.../Pods/BuildHeaders/SVGKit/SVGRect.h:40:42: No newline at end of file
```

Comment: What version of Cocoapods are you using? What warning are you seeing?